# How to make animations and gesture recognisers work together? (Swift)

Tags: ios, swift, animation, uigesturerecognizer

I made a simple project, with swipe gesture recogniser and animation. I made my  label to move and every 3 second increase number. With every swipe I need to decrease the number. My gesture recogniser object is tied with label, i.e. it works only in label bounds. When prog is working without animation everything is ok, but when it;s animated an is moving my gesture recogniser is doing nothing. How to make a gesture recogniser work at the same time as animation, i.e. while animated to respond to my swipes. Need help.

`

```
 @IBOutlet weak var label1: UILabel!

var number : Int = 0
var timer = Timer()

@IBAction func label1SwipeRight(_ sender: UISwipeGestureRecognizer) {
    number += 1
    label1.text = String(number)
}

func animate1() {
    UIView.animate(withDuration: 4.0, delay: 0.0, options: .allowUserInteraction, animations: {
        let num1 : CGFloat = CGFloat(arc4random_uniform(667))
        let num2 : CGFloat = CGFloat(arc4random_uniform(375))
        self.label1.frame.origin.y = num1
        self.label1.frame.origin.x = num2
    }, completion: {(bool) in
        self.animate1()
        print("Animation1 completed")
    })
}

func timerExample() {
    Timer.scheduledTimer(timeInterval: 4, target: self, selector: #selector(updateTimer), userInfo: nil, repeats: true)

}

@objc func updateTimer() {
    label1.text = String(Int(label1.text!)! + 1)
}`
```

Comment: that would be more helpful to show some code.

Comment: here, added code (first time animate1 func is called in viewDidLoad )

Comment: Use UIViewPropertyAnimator. It does this for you automatically (makes animated view tappable, even allowing you drag the animated view and interrupt the animation if that's what you want).

Answer (score 7, accepted):

By default view objects block user interaction while an animation is "in flight". You need to use one of the "long form" animation methods, and pass in the option `.allowUserInteraction`. Something like this:

```
UIView.animate(duration: 0.5,
  delay: 0.0,
  options: .allowUserInteraction,
  animations: {
    myView.alpha = 0.5
  })
```

Note, however, that if what you're animating is a view's position, the user won't be able to tap on the view object as it moves. That's because a position animation does not really animate the object from one place to another over time. It just creates that appearance. Behind the scenes, the object actually jumps to it's final position the moment the animation begins.

If you need to be able to tap/drag/swipe on objects while they're moving you will have to do that yourself. What you do is put a gesture recognizer on the parent view that encloses the entire range of motion (possibly the whole screen.) Then you need to use the presentation layer of your animating view's layer, translate the coordinates of the point from the gesture recognizer's coordinate space to the layer's coordinate space, and use the layer's hitTest method to figure out if the point is on the layer or not.

I have a project on Github called [**iOS-CAAnimation-group-demo**](https://github.com/BikeLoverChina/iOS-CAAnimation-group-demo) that does something like that (It animates an image view along a complex path and you can tap on the image view to pause the animation while it's "in flight".

It's from several years ago, so it's written in Objective-C, but it should help to at least illustrate the technique.

Comment: Yea, I need to swipe on moving object , at least that was the objective. Later there should be a lot more moving objects an I need to swipe them out. I need to be able to interact with that object at all possible times if possible. Your answer helped a little and now I can interact at the end of animation before start of next, but still it's not entirely that what I need

Comment: See the edit to my answer then. I added a link to a project that handles taps on a view.